# Jq to filter streaming data in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, streaming, jq, input-filtering

I'm trying to figure out how to filter data that is being forwarded from one port to another.

What I'm doing is taking in data from an indoor positioning system and importing it into my Oracle database. Here is the script I'm using to forward the data and it works great.

Basically my indoor positioning system will only connect to port 8787 and my database pulls in data from port 8081.

```
import socket
port = 8787
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(("", port))
print ("waiting on port:", port)
while 1:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    s.sendto(data, ('192.1.1.1',8788))
```

And here is the data its streaming:

> {"id":"0xDECA34303170235F","timestamp":946684889.332,"msgid":78,"coordinates":{"x":0.392,"y":0.616,"z":1.228,"heading":0.000,"pqf":100},"meas":[{"anchor":"0xDECA353034301E99","dist":1.433,"dqf":100},{"anchor":"0xDECA323030901DE2","dist":8.307,"dqf":100},{"anchor":"0xDECA323031300FBF","dist":6.288,"dqf":89},{"anchor":"0xDECA333035101DAA","dist":10.308,"dqf":87}]}

Here is what I need instead:

> [
>     "0xDECA34303170235F",
>     946684889.332,
>     78,
>     0.392,
>     0.616,
>     1.228,
>     0
>   ]

I got that from setting up a filter and running sample data through it via [jqplay](http://www.jqplay.org). Here is the filter that I used to get that;

```
 [.id, .timestamp, .msgid, .coordinates["x","y","z","heading"]]
```

What I'm trying to figure out is where to put those filters into my forwarding script so the data can be filtered before it's forwarded. Any missing data has to be null for the database.

I'm using Python 2.7 On Windows 8 and I downloaded and installed jq via choco.

Comment: It might just be easier to do it in pure python.  The json module should be adequate. Otherwise, you could use subprocesses to pipe calls to and from `jq`. Search for python questions on how to do that.

Comment: There is a windows port of "netcat": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat#Ports_and_reimplementations

Comment: Excellent! Thanks Jeff and peak!